# How Daily Active Devices in PubNub are counted

Tags: websocket, publish-subscribe, pubnub

As a contrived example, if the twitter datastream example from:
 https://www.pubnub.com/developers/realtime-data-streams/twitter-stream/
was implemented in a website.

Is each new visitor using that website counted in the daily active devices quota? PubNub's free tier gives only 100 daily active devices and the next upgrade to 1000 is $150.

Using the free tier, will I only be able to have 100 unique visits on a simple twitter stream before my quota runs out?

Or once a visitor closes the tab, I can give the next new visitor the same UUID, effectively reducing the quota to mean 100 visitors simultaneously.

Maybe since every visitor subscribes to the same channel, I can give each visitor the same UUID, making the limiting quota messages sent. What will happen if multiple user's are initialized with the same UUID?

Perhaps this isn't really a good use case for PubNub and this example should probably be implemented using a custom solution.

Does the same apply for a website implementing a TIC-TAC-TOE game, only 100 unique visitors a day? or only 50 games (100 players) simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

### PubNub Daily Active Devices and Pricing

The [DADs (daily active devices) are counted as each unique IP address](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/301/how-are-active-devices-counted) that connects to PubNub, so yes, you would likely go over the Free tier limits very quickly, but we do have custom pricing plans for *drive-by* web traffic that makes it more fairly priced.

UUIDs are just that – unique ID per client (subscriber) and is used for our Presence service but also helps for identifying unique devices/users.

For details on custom pricing, you can contact PubNub Support - which you already have :)